# Metal shader interpolate values in buffer

Tags: ios, fragment-shader, metal, metalkit

I need to pass a buffer to Metal fragment shader which is an array of N float values. But I want the shader to interpolate values if the width of the texture to which it is drawn is more than N pixels. If I use a texture, it is easy to use sampler and set linear filtering, but it's not clear if interpolation can be setup on an arbitrary buffer in fragment shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to make Metal interpolate over values in a buffer for you. Metal has no way of knowing that the buffer has an associated "geometry". For example, an array of N float values could be N horizontal elements, N vertical elements, 5 rows of N/5 elements, etc. Interpolation requires knowledge of which elements are neighbors of a given element, which requires knowledge of geometry.

You can, of course, do the interpolation yourself in the shader.

You can also create a texture from a buffer using the `-newTextureWithDescriptor:...`/`makeTexture()` method of `MTLBuffer`. Then you can sample from that texture.

Comment: What's the cost of repeatedly creating a texture in every render cycle, vs creating a texture once and then repeatedly modifying it using the buffer bytes? Assuming data is less than 1K bytes.

Comment: Probably creating the texture once will be faster, but nobody is going to be able to answer that definitely. It can vary with hardware and OS version. You can try measuring the performance on a reasonably representative subset of the hardware and OS versions that you're targeting.